# bucket script not working - elasticsearch 2.4.2

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I have tried to subtract the aggregations

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,  
  "aggs": {
      "total_query_id": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "query_id"
          }
        },

      "total_num_results": {
        "sum": {
          "field": "num_results"
        }
    },               
    "minus_value": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "qid": "total_query_id",
              "nrs": "total_num_results"
            },
            "script": "qid - nrs"
          }
        } 
    }  
}
```

it throws the below error

> "reason": "Invalid pipeline aggregation named [minus_value] of type [bucket_script]. Only sibling pipeline aggregations are allowed at the top level"

I have moved to back and forth **minus_value** node to aggs node but it does not solve my problem.

can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Have you tried to wrap them all inside a `global{}` aggregation?

Comment: what do you mean? without `minus_value` node it will return both value of aggregation but when I try to subtract these values using bucket script it throws error. by the by I am new to this may be lack of what you ask

Comment: The idea is that pipeline aggregations must work on a parent bucket aggregation. It is not the case in your example, so you must have one parent aggregation (e.g. [try `global` since you have a `match_all` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html))  and embed your 3 aggregations inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that pipeline aggregations must work on a parent bucket aggregation.

It is not the case in your example, so you must have one parent aggregation. Since you have a `match_all` query, you could try using a [`global`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-global-aggregation.html) bucket aggregation and then embed your 3 aggregations inside it, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "all": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "total_query_id": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "query_id"
          }
        },
        "total_num_results": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "num_results"
          }
        },
        "minus_value": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "qid": "total_query_id",
              "nrs": "total_num_results"
            },
            "script": "qid - nrs"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I will be back to you buddy. I have tight works. give me sometime to experiment after that I accept your answer :-)

Comment: No worries, I was just curious if it worked out. Take your time.

Comment: @Val i am also facing the same problem but i am not using a match_all query . will this work even then? if i wrap inside a global{} ?